# Генерация ссылки ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый вечер

пишу сайт на ASP.NET MVC

Есть поле во вьюхе

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().Link, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Ссылка" } })
```

в который надо сгенерировать и вставить ссылку на другой контроллер

например это будет `"Welcome", "Intervier"`

Генериться оно должно по нажатию кнопки.и появляться в поле

Как это реализовать?

**АПДЕЙТ**

Порылся по форумам и вышел на такой вариант

В Контроллере написал такой код

```
   string myRouteUrl = Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Interwier", action = "Welcome" });
ViewBag.Link = myRouteUrl;
```

То есть формально я получаю роут к контроллеру

На Вьюхе пробовал вывести так для начала

```
 <b>@ViewBag.Link</b>
```

Выводит только

> /Interwier/Welcome

Comment: `Html.ActionLink`

Comment: Вопрос в том, как записать значение в EditorFor по кнопке?@Igor

Comment: это Вам на клиенте придется делать, если Вы не хотите перегружать страницу по нажатию той кнопки. Что должно появиться в инпуте?

Comment: Смотри, логика такая, пользователь нажимает кнопку, в инпуте повляется просто ссылка на контроллер.

то есть например `https://smartvideo.com/Interwier/Welcome`

Я сейчас обновлю пост, нашел некоторый вариант, но не знаю насколько правильно

@Igor

Comment: Обновил свой пост@Igor

Comment: ну дак сгенерите и заполните ссылку, а потом вставьте в эдитор. То есть сначала выполните, что у вас во второй части поста, а потом в первой, только не во вьюбэг передавайте а в искомый `model.first().link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно сделать на клиенте, если генериться должно по нажатию кнопки, то на событие `onclick()`

```
$( "#mybutton" ).click(function() {
    $("#myinput").val('@Url.Action("Welcome", "Intervier")')
});
```

Comment: хм, окей, я попробую так, потому что спосов который я описал, немного глупый

Comment: Смотри, все отлично работает, но, получаю только `/Interwier/Welcome`

а хотелось бы получать полный адрес

Comment: все, решил трабл